# bash: setup.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the instructions in Chap 3 of Learning Robotics Using Python (Ubuntu 14.04), I added the ROS workspace path.

```
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

When starting a new terminal I get the message in the question line.
Is anything wrong?
Chet

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223315/bash:-setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-12-31**:
Have you run catkin make in the workspace yet ?
Does the file setup.bash exist in your workspace, and is that the correct path to it ?

**Comment by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on 2015-12-31**:
nickw:

1. I ran catkin make
2. setup.bash is in /opt/ros/indigo but I don't know how to determine whether it is in my workspace

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-01**:
the line added to the .bashrc file is trying to read a file  ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Error is the file is not there. you don't have a workspace set up, different name than catkin_ws, or location. More on setting up http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The others are right--you didn't run catkin_make yet. Make sure you did all these steps:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I put semicolons as line terminators because the newlines aren't showing in my answer. Just a bit of extra safety, that's all.

---

Originally posted by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) with karma: 187 on 2016-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-03**:\

> I put semicolons as line terminators because the newlines aren't showing in my answer.

That's because you didn't format it as *Preformatted text*. Use the button with `101010` on it next time.

**Comment by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) on 2016-01-03**:
Cool! I didn't understand what that button was at first glance--thanks for the tip!

**Comment by [ptreyesguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/25433/ptreyesguy/) on 2016-01-03**:
Thank you all. Now I can open a new terminal without nasty messages.
Chet

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2016-01-05**:
If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as "Correct" (Just click the ✓ icon). Thank you for keeping the forum clean and well organised!

**Comment by [Pytron](https://answers.ros.org/users/109226/pytron/) on 2022-06-25**:
I was working on a project. I installed husky_ws but then I deleted it. When I open a new terminal, it says " bash: /home/lenovo/husky_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory ". I can't revert to catkin_ws. I did what you said, but nothing has changed. What should I do?